# Is it possible for a chi-square distribution to have unit variance?

Tags: self-study, variance, chi-squared-distribution

I have a problem set from a professor that has me puzzling. Here's the problem:

x and y are i.i.d Gaussian random variables with a mean of zero and unit variance. What is the mean and variance of |z|<sup>2</sup>, when z = x + jy? How would we obtain a random variable with the same distribution as |z|<sup>2</sup> but with unit variance?

So, from what I can tell, |z| = $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, therefore: |z|<sup>2</sup> = x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>

That part isn't confusing for me. So now that I have this equation for |z|<sup>2</sup>, it seems obvious that this is a chi-square distribution, since x and y are both i.i.d and standard normal distributions. With these values in mind, I calculated the mean to be n = 2 since there are 2 degrees of freedom and the variance = 2n = 4.

What confuses me is the last part of the question. How could I create a chi-square distribution with unit variance? Wouldn't the degrees of freedom then need to be 1/2? Is that possible?

Comment: "same distribution but with unit variance" is slightly strange, putting pressure on *same*, but I would just scale it suitably, i.e. multiply all the values by a suitable constant.  Incidentally, it is worth knowing that a chi-squared distribution with two degrees of freedom is a particular exponential distribution.

Comment: So in terms of scaling, would I multiple by 1/2 or 1/4? Since multiplying n by 1/2 would give me a 2n = 1, but if I'm scaling the whole thing, would multiplying by 1/4 change the variance to 1?

Answer (score 1):

To start, look at the rule for $Var(aX + b)$ in terms of $Var(X).$

If $Q\sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=1),$ then $Var(Q) = 2$ and $Var(Q/2)=?,\;Var(Q/\sqrt{2}) = ?$

But neither $Q/2$ nor $Q/\sqrt{2}$ has a chi-squared distribution.